# DataGridView.row.headercell.value displays only 10 characters

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I have powershell code that displays the result in DataGridView using windows.forms and I want to display the index number in each row. But the index values are only displayed from 1 to 9, and after that it is reset to 1:

[image]

```
$DataGridView.Rows | % { $_.HeaderCell.Value = ($_.Index +1).ToString() }
```

I tried to change

```
$DataGridView.Rows | % { $_.HeaderCell.Value = ($_.Index).ToString() }
```

But it doesn't produce results

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share `$DataGridView` origin.

Comment: Try to resize the column width : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/resizing-columns-and-rows-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8  Usually I just make the DGV datasource a datatable.  Every once i a while the DGV gets corrupted and doesn't work properly.  I found simply deleting the DGV and adding a new one solves these issues.

Comment: @jdweng You were right. I resized 
$datagridview.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode     = 'AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders'
$datagridview.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth($datagridview.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode )
And now everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jdweng thx. I resized RowHeaders
`$datagridview.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = 'AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders' $datagridview.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth($datagridview.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode)`
And now everything works.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution. Curiously, your screenshot seems to indicate that the column has enough space for multi-digit numbers - are the numbers perhaps left-space-padded? Note that _one_ of your two commands should suffice: Use `$datagridview.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = 'AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders'` if you want to _keep auto-resizing_ the columns when new rows are added later. Use `$datagridview.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth('AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders')` to auto-resize _once_, based on the then-current rows.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks)
And about the space. I checked there aren't any...